# How to Determine if an Int is 16 Bits

Tags: c, architecture, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm working with bitwise and logical operators in C. I'm familiar with concept and purpose of these operators, but have run into bit of a problem.

I need to determine whether an integer `x` can fit into a short. I am restricted to using the operators `! ~ & ^ | + << >>`. Also, I can only use up to 8 of these operators.

I know from several other posts (like this one: [How to tell if a 32 bit int can fit in a 16 bit short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337526/how-to-tell-if-a-32-bit-int-can-fit-in-a-16-bit-short)) that a solution like

`!(((((x) & 0xffff8000) >> 15) + 1) & 0x1fffe)`

would work just fine (credit to Emil Romanus). However, I'm also forbidden to use any constants that are not `0x0` and `0xff`.

I'm mostly confused on the logic here. Any ideas?

EDIT: I forgot to mention conditional statement are also forbidden. So no ifs, elses, loops etc.

Comment: `!0x0 == 1` ... `!0x0 + !0x0 == 2` ... just saying :)

Comment: @pmg ahhhh I'm catching your drift

Comment: First of all, do you know the size of `int` and the size of `short` for your arquitecture/compiler? Assuming `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int32_t)`, and `sizeof(short) == sizeof(int16_t)` is a big assumption.

Answer (score 1):

that is your sollution

```
 (unsigned)~0 == 0xffff
```

or without `==`

```
 !((unsigned)~0 - 0xffff)

 !((unsigned)~0 ^ 0xffff)
```

or if only 0xff is allowed

```
!((unsigned)~0 ^ (((0xff << (!!0xff << !!0xff << !!0xff << !!0xff))) | 0xff)))
```

Comment: I sort of see what you're doing, but why add two `!` operators next to each `0xff`? Wouldn't that just negate the negation? Also, I'm supposed to only use 8 operators at the maximum.

Comment: I need number `1`. `!!` converts any non zero to `1`

Comment: then 3rd sollution. There is no other way

Comment: @P__J__ hold my beer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For readability set `invuint = ~0u` and `invushort = ~((short)0u)`, than we can do `invuint - invushort` which is either `0` or not. `0` in standard C is equal to `false`, so you can see with a simple `!(invuint - invushort)` if an `unsigned int` fits into an `unsigned short`.

But that is most likely not what you are asked to do, it would be a bit too easy. If you need to know if the content of an `unsigned int` fits into an `unsigned short` it gets a bit more complicated.

We can reuse the `incushort = ~((short)0u)` here as a mask.

With `an_uint = 0; an_uint = incushort` we set the lowest bits of `an_uint` to ones so we have `0x0000ffff`. Reversing that with `~an_uint` gets you `0xXXXX0000` where the `X` stand for an unknown number of ones. So if `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(unsigned short)` we get a `0` but we could have gotten that simpler, see above.

If we use `mask = 0xXXXX0000` as a mask to get all of the bits that are larger than an `unsigned short` with `uint_with_unknown_content & mask` we get a `0` if `uint_with_unknown_content` fits into an `unsigned short`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is based on the fact that `x^(x<<1)` will have its 16 MSB at zero iff the 17 MSB of `x`  are all equal and `x` can be coded on 16 bits.

Hence

```
return (x^(x<<1))&(0xffff0000)==0;
```

solves the problem.

For readability, operations are split in several instructions and 
to reduce the number of used operators the final test is reversed (it does not seem to be forbidden).

```
int canNOTbemappedto16bits(int x) {
   int one = !0x0;  // 1 op
   int ffff = (unsigned short) ~0x0;//1 op
   int ffff0000 = (unsigned int) ~0x0 ^ ffff; // 2ops
   return   (x^(x<<one))&ffff0000 ; // 3ops
}
```

7 ops!

Comment: I like your logic and your answer is very clear and concise, but how would I go about this without using the `-` operator? Also, I am only allowed to use 8 operators.

Comment: I missed the fact that "-" was fordidden. But the only operation required is "-1" and it can be replaced by +(~0). Concerning the number of operators, it fits, but not with a oneliner. I update the answer.

Comment: @vastImmortalSuns There was a bug in previous answer, but I found a much simpler way that fully respects the constraints.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks for clearing that up, I didn't realize that you could even negate 0, but now that makes perfect sense :)